# Final Cut Pro X — Connect audio clip to another audio (not video)

Tags: video-editor, audio, final-cut-pro-x, mixing

I have a simple video with some background noises added and a background audio track.
However, background audio track is too long, so I carefully cut it into multiple pieces and seamlessly mix:

[image: Final Cut Pro X — Mixing Background Music]

It works fine, but my second audio part is now connected to the video on top — every next change in the timeline will break my carefully mixed audiotracks.
I want it to be connected to the first *audio* part instead.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a compound clip with the music on the audio track. This will fix them in place. Replace the individual clips with the compound clip.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (To create a compound clip you select clips and press ⌥G)